# Connect to sql server 2008 using Microsoft Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have difficulties connecting to my MS SQL Server and I can't find tutorial or answer how to do this, even though I think this should be something pretty standard.

My current setup is this - I have freshly new Installed Visual `Studio 2010` and followed `Beth Massi's` article `Step-by-Step: Installing SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Express after Visual Studio 2010` : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010.aspx

But I'm not able to connect to a SQL Server. In my `Configuration Tools\SQL Server Configuration Manager` I see this when I open it :

[image: Configuration Manager Main View]

I set to `Enable` all `TCP\IP` and `Named Pipes` (Just saw that this may be a problem) and in the properties of the `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` from Services I see this:

[image: SQL config properties]

I also see in the `Log On` tab this :

[image: SQL conf pass]

some sort of password (not entered by me) it seems to be something default, but since I'm not sure where the problem is I try to show everything I think may have something to do with solving my problem.

At the end I tried different options to connect to my SQL Server form the Management Studio I ended up with this:

[image: SQL management studio and Error]

As you see I get an error (included in order to be able to read it). I read the the machine name may be required so my User Account name is `Xman` and my machine's name is `Xman-PC`. Eveh though my printscreen image is not from this try I made an attempt to connect to the Server with `XMAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS` but again - no success.\

Could you point me to a good tutorial on how to connect to a MS SQL Server (I can't believe there's nothing that explains in simple steps what you need to do to connect to a server) or could you tell me how to set-up my configurations so I actually can start to work with databases?

P.S

Forgot to mention in `Command Prompyt` - `sqlcmd` command also returns error - `Could not open SQL connection`.

P.S

Finally I managed to connect using `Windows Authentication` and `(local)\sqlexpress` for ServerName. Which at least means that everything is working. But now even more I would like to know how to connect using `SQL Server Authentication`. It must be something default as it was for `Windows Authentication`?!

Comment: Have you tried starting the SQL Browser Service?

Comment: No, I'm gonna. How can I know the default data that I need to provide for SQL Authentication? Thanks!

Comment: It should be Windows Authentication, unless you did something different during the installation.

Comment: I want to use SQL Authentication. The installation was done with defaults. I started SQL Browser Service - now when I try with MachineName OR User for Login I was getting first - `Connection succeed but no answer on the other side of the pipe` or something similar and after that on every try I get `Connection failed` This happens with starting SQL Browser Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've done the hard work - last step will be turning on SQL Server Authentication.

Since you installed with the default values, only **Windows Authentication** is allowed; you need to set it to **SQL Server and Windows Authentication** mode. You can do this through Management Studio through the instance **Properties** -> **Security**.

See this link for full details: [Change Server Authentication Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: `A connection was successfully established with the server but then  an error occurred during the login process. (provide : Shared memory provider, error : 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.` - any idea what may cause this error?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, this was cause because I wasn't activate the `sa` login. But yet I cant connect. It seems that the Server Name is by default not the same for the SQL Server Authentication

Comment: No idea why it has to be so difficult but finally I made it. Thanks. Your answer and this - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/16706dec-209f-42c4-8dc7-4ee4dd5df482/ made it possible. In case someone else is trying to do the same.